# Transform object using TypeScript / Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following object in Typescript / Javascript:

```
{
    "portfolio": {
        "name": "portfolio 1",
        "performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 1}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 2}],
        "funds": [
            {
                "name": "fund 1",
                "performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 3}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 4}],
            },
            {
                "name": "fund 2",
                "performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 5}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 6}],
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I transform it to the following format:

```
{
    "headers": ["date", "portfolio 1", "fund 1", "fund 2"],
    "data": [
                ["2022-01-01", "1", "3", "5"],
                ["2022-02-01", "2", "4", "6"]
            ]
}
```

Comment: Why is `"portfolio1"` part of `"headers"`? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I was to combine performance series of portfolio and funds. I have tried doing it but the code is not compliable so havent posted it here.

Comment: @developer If you've tried, please show us that attempt and the error messages you've encountered.

Comment: Where do the results "1" and "2" come from? Is that an index? Why is it a string and not a number? Why are "3", "4", "5", "6" strings? Is that really what you want?

Comment: these are just sample data., they are not index. They can be converted to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to transpose the inner structure of the input object.

Here is how you can make it happen:

```js
const data = {"portfolio": {"name": "portfolio 1","performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 1}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 2}],"funds": [{"name": "fund 1","performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 3}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 4}],},{"name": "fund 2","performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 5}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 6}],}]}};

const {name, performance, funds} = data.portfolio;
const result = {
    headers: ["date", name, ... funds.map(({name}) => name)],
    data: performance.map(({date, value}, i) => 
        [date, value, ...funds.map(({performance: {[i]: {value}}}) => value)]
    )
};

console.log(result);
```

Note that some of the output data is numeric. I suppose that is more useful that the strings you have listed in your desired output. If you really want strings, then just convert them by doing `performance[i].value+""` and `=> value+""`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I was looking for similar code where instead of doing manual for loops, we can use javascript map function to create similar output.

Comment: It seems the code is using index instead of performance value (1,2,3..). The other question I had was, how can I merge the data when there are different dates for portfolio and funds. E.g. Portfolio may have some extra dates while fund may not have data for those dates. I need to use portfolio's dates as base and merge fund's data to those dates. I have tried to replicate in: https://jsfiddle.net/mkdeveloper2021/o30nbf6j/4/

Comment: Updated the snippet to use the performance value. It was a bit of a guess work, as in your question it was not explained where every value originated from.

Comment: As to the other question, that seems to be a new question. Can I invite you to describe these particular needs in a new question?

Comment: yes sure, I will raise another question. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603070/merge-data-using-javascript-typescript raised.