# Merge data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to merge performance data using portfolio as base.

```js
const data = {"portfolio": {"name": "portfolio 1","performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 100},{"date": "2022-01-15","value": 150}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 200}],"funds": [{"name": "fund 1","performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 3}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 4}],},{"name": "fund 2","performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 5}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 6}, {"date": "2022-03-01","value": 7}]}]}};

const {name, performance, funds} = data.portfolio;
const result = {
    headers: ["date", name, ... funds.map(({name}) => name)],
    data: funds[0].performance.map(({date, value}, i) => 
        [date, performance[i].value, ...funds.map(({performance: {[i]: {value}}}) => value)]
    )
};

console.log(result);
```

Current result:

```
{
  data: [["2022-01-01", 100, 3, 5], ["2022-02-01", 150, 4, 6]],
  headers: ["date", "portfolio 1", "fund 1", "fund 2"]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
  headers: ["date", "portfolio 1", "fund 1", "fund 2"],
  data: [["2022-01-01", 100,3, 5], ["2020-01-15", 150, , ], ["2022-02-01", 200, 4, 6]]
}
```

Note that it does not include "2022-03-01" as portfolio does not have it.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mkdeveloper2021/o30nbf6j/9/

Comment: There isn't any trace of TypeScript in the code you posted. Apart from some shortcut expressions, TypeScript does not bring any change to the JavaScript language. It only adds types and the types are removed during the compilation to JavaScript without changing the actual code. Tag the question with the correct language.

Comment: [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) provide an experience similar to JSfiddle, but provides the code here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: Sure, I will correct the title and remove typescript tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in this structure the performance arrays *per fund* do not necessarily have the same length as the global performance arrays, the matching entries do not occur at the same index, and must be explicitly matched by date.

In other words, the part that destructures a parameter with `{[i]: {value}}` needs to be replaced by a different solution. You'll have to *find* the right index. I suggest to use `find` for that:

```js
const data = {"portfolio": {"name": "portfolio 1","performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 100}, {"date": "2022-01-15","value": 150}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 200}], "funds": [{"name": "fund 1","performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 3}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 4}],},{"name": "fund 2","performance": [{"date": "2022-01-01","value": 5}, {"date": "2022-02-01","value": 6}],}]}};

const {name, performance, funds} = data.portfolio;
const result = {
    headers: ["date", name, ...funds.map(({name}) => name)],
    data: performance.map(({date, value}, i) => 
        [date, value, ...funds.map(({performance}) => 
            performance.find(item => item.date == date)?.value
        )]
    )
};

console.log(result);
```